# Regexp: Match value if condition occurs

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like
`Value = ('1 OR 2') OR Value = ('THREE OR FOUR')`
and I want to split it by **OR** (that one is not in quotes).
How can I do it with regexp? It has to match only if I have an even number of quotes before **OR**.
Is it possible?
I tried use `[\w\W]*?'[\w\W]*(\sOR\s)` but it works incorrect, it takes only last **OR**, even if it is inside quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[\w\W]` can match any character including `'`

You could make use of lookaround with an infinite quantifier in C# and match optional pairs of single quotes.

If you want all pairs of single quotes in the whole string, you can also assert them to the right.

If you don't want to cross matching newline, you can use `[^'\r\n]*` instead of `[^']*`

```
(?<=^(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*)\bOR\b(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind

  - `^(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*` Match optional pairs or single quotes from the start of the string
- `)` Close lookbehind

  - `\bOR\b` Match OR between word boundaries
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$` Match optional pairs of quotes till the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%29*%5b%5e%27%5d*%29%5cbOR%5cb%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%29*%5b%5e%27%5d*%24%29&i=Value+%3d+%28%271+OR+2%27%29+OR+Value+%3d+%28%27THREE+OR+FOUR%27%29%0d%0aValue+%3d+%28%271+OR+2%27%29+OR+Value+%3d+%28%27THREE+OR+FOUR%27%29+test+%27%27+OR+%27%27+OR&o=m)

Comment: The lookahead is surely unnecessary and is incorrect in any case: the `(?:'[^'\r\n]*')*` pattern is not likely to match where there are multiple pairs of single quotes in the rest of the string because it insists that the closing quote of a pair is immediately followed by the opening quote of the next pair.

Comment: @MikeM Ah yes, the leading negated character class should be in the repeating group.

Answer (score 0):

Using a positive lookbehind ensures that `OR` is only matched if it is preceded by an even number of single quotes (and surrounded by whitespace as in your regex).

```
(?<=^(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*)\sOR\s
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to match everything that is valid and use `Regex.Matches` to get all the sub-strings?

```
var splitRE = new Regex(@"([^'OR]+|O[^R]|'[^']*'|(?<!O)R|(?<=\w)OR|OR(?=\w))+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var ans = splitRE.Matches(s);
```

Basically the pattern matches anything not a single-quote, O, or R OR matches O and following not an R OR matches a single-quoted string OR matches an R not preceded by an O OR matches an OR preceded by a word character OR matches an OR followed by a word character.